# How to extract the IP of the string using RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, string, ip

How to extract the IP of the string below using RegEx?

```
... sid [1544764] srv [CFT256] remip [10.0.128.31] fwf []...
```

I tried the code below but did not return the expected value:

```
string pattern = @"remip\ \[.\]";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(stringToSearch, pattern );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b" will match ip addresses generally

Comment: @Andrew: well, this will match 999.999.999.999 as well

Comment: @Vlad... yes, but matching **valid** ip addresses using a regex seems like a nightmare scenario, my expression is pretty solid for pulling out likely candidates.

Comment: @Andrew: I wonder if 0000127.0.0.00000001 is a valid IP address :-P

Comment: @Vlad my expression wont match that due to the word boundaries. Granted it would match 0000.127.0.0.0.0000001, but then that's just getting fussy! (also I posted as a comment rather than an answer as I thought it might be helpful for him but wasn't a specific answer to his question, where it's better to use the remip context)

Comment: @Andrew: I've just tried with W7's ping: it accepts 127.0.0.0000001 (and interprets it as 127.0.0.1), but for 00000127.0.0.1 it treats 127 as octal and pings 87.0.0.1 (87dec happens to be 127oct).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11061/discussion-between-andrew-barrett-and-vlad)

Comment: @Andrew: your regexp wouldn't match 0000.127.0.0.0.0000001, since 0000001 isn't \d{1,3}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
@"remip \[(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\]"
```

To clarify... the reason yours doesn't work is because you are only matching `.` inside the `[` and `]`. A single `.` matches only a single character. You could add a `*` (zero or more) or a `+` (one or more) to make it work. In addition, surrounding it with parenthesis: `(` and `)`, means you can extract just the IP address directly from the second item in the `MatchCollection`.

Comment: Prob should add a backslash before your '.' match.

Comment: @Jon Grant, would be better if it was \d{1,3} to ensure it is at most three characters, and a minimum of one.

Comment: @M yeah I considered that. It depends how specific they want to be. Going the other way you could match simply `[0-9.]+`

Answer (score 4):

If you switch the pattern to

```
string pattern = @"remip\s*\[[^\]]*\]";
```

you will be able to match an address string even if it has errors (e.g. contains non-digits, not enough dots, etc.). You will most likely end up validating the address in code anyway, so this may be a good idea to capture what was *intended* to be used as an IP address, validate it explicitly in your code, and produce a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can use grouping with your Regex:

```
@"remip\s\[(?<IP>\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)\]"
```

It will return the result in the "IP" Group

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
string pattern = @"remip\s\[.+?\]";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(stringToSearch, pattern );
```

Comment: perhaps `\s*`, in order to be more flexible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one .

```
String zeroTo255
            = "(\\d{1,2}|(0|1)\\"
              + "d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])";
 
        // Regex for a digit from 0 to 255 and
        // followed by a dot, repeat 4 times.
        // this is the regex to validate an IP address.
        String regex
            = zeroTo255 + "\\."
              + zeroTo255 + "\\."
              + zeroTo255 + "\\."
              + zeroTo255;
 
    
        
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, regex );
```